# Erasing whole JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

do you know the best way to erase whole JT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it like HEBERT suggested, you break the link between your data object and your table model.  Bad MVC design.

Ideally, you have access to the data model.  Assuming it's a List in the variable myDataList

```
myDataList.clear();
myTable.getModel().fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: Did you even read my post ? Your post is about the ideal situation, mine is about the worse case scenario...

Comment: -1, you should not be modifying the "data list" which contains the data. You should modify the TableModel directly. The DefaultTableModel has a method setRowCount() method which will clear the data for you. If you have a custom model then you will need to add a clear() method which will then fire the table data changed method.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your model. If you can access it, modify its content, else :

```
yourJTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
```

Comment: I did read your post, which is why I needed to answer the question correctly.